# Replace a value based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(drug = c("__Drug A__", "__NA__", "__Drug B__", "__NA__", "__Drug C__", "__NA__"))
```

and would like to replace `__NA__` values with a preciding value so that the final column will be

```
df <- data.frame(drug = c("__Drug A__", "__Drug A__", "__Drug B__", "__Drug B__", "__Drug C__", "__Drug C__"))
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advanceQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first replace the values with NA and after that `fill` them down like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(drug = na_if(drug, "__NA__")) %>%
  fill(drug, .direction = "down")
#>         drug
#> 1 __Drug A__
#> 2 __Drug A__
#> 3 __Drug B__
#> 4 __Drug B__
#> 5 __Drug C__
#> 6 __Drug C__
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time and assisting me

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `lag()` function from `dplyr` here:

```r
library(dplyr)
df$drug <- ifelse(df$drug == "__NA__", lag(df$drug), df$drug)
df$drug

[1] "__Drug A__" "__Drug A__" "__Drug B__" "__Drug B__" "__Drug C__"
[6] "__Drug C__"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in Base R using a loop:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
    if(df$drug[i]=="__NA__"){
        df$drug[i] <- df$drug[i-1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time and assisting me